# Zoom audio dropouts when using Bluetooth mouse and truly wireless in-ear Bluetooth headphones

Tags: windows-10, audio, mouse, bluetooth, zoom-meeting

I have two (or rather three) Bluetooth devices: the [Creative Outlier Air](https://en.creative.com/p/headphones-headsets/creative-outlier-air) in-ear wireless headphones and the [Microsoft Bluetooth Mouse](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/microsoft-bluetooth-mouse/8QBX2W3XSP2H?activetab=pivot%3Aoverviewtab), all connected to my Toshiba Satellite laptop. My Bluetooth adapter is the Qualcomm Atheros AR3012 Bluetooth 4.0. My issue is that when all three components are connected to my computer, I get frequent audio dropouts in the [Zoom Video Conferencing](https://zoom.us/) platform. Music and video playback on YouTube, Netflix, and other platforms works fine. So far I have found four (non-ideal) fixes:

1. Praying, disconnecting, and reconnecting the headphones until the dropouts stop.
2. Disabling the headphones' telephony service and repeating option 1 (this is a little more likely to solve the dropouts).
3. Turning off the mouse (this always solves the dropouts).
4. Keeping one of the headphones turned off (this also always works).

I have also tried updating drivers and all that, to no avail. Previously I had an issue where my mouse would randomly disconnect, but disabling the "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power" option in the Bluetooth adapter solved this.
The dropouts might be due to a hardware limitation in the bandwidth or the number of channels the adapter can handle. However, since this problem only affects Zoom, I believe there may be some software trick to solve it.

Comment: Try a USB Bluetooth adapter and see if that works any better.

Answer (score 0):

Try only using the earbuds for sound and your computer for the microphone.  I was having a similar issue where all my other bluetooth devices would disconnect when I connected my headphones.